# How to unbalance bibliography columns in latex?

Tags: latex, biblatex

I would like the two columns of the references to be uneven, such as that the references appear on the left column until there is no more space, and then on the right column. Thanks in advance!

This is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber, natbib = true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{output.bib} 

\title{Paper title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\cite{author1}
\cite{author2}
\cite{author3}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Bibliography code:

```
@article{author1,
  title={The title of the Article is this},
  author={Author and Author and Author and Author and Author},
  journal={Journal where article was published},
  volume={7},
  number={6},
  pages={259--270},
  year={2015},
  publisher={publisher}
}

@article{author2,
  title={Article Title},
  author={Author and Author},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={7},
  number={6},
  pages={259--270},
  year={2015},
  publisher={publisher}
}

@article{author3,
  title={Article Title},
  author={Author and Author},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={7},
  number={6},
  pages={259--270},
  year={2015},
  publisher={publisher}
}
```

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/85KzW.png

Answer (score 1):

Using the `flushend` package:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber, natbib = true]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{flushend}



\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{author1,
  title={The title of the Article is this},
  author={Author and Author and Author and Author and Author},
  journal={Journal where article was published},
  volume={7},
  number={6},
  pages={259--270},
  year={2015},
  publisher={publisher}
}

@article{author2,
  title={Article Title},
  author={Author and Author},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={7},
  number={6},
  pages={259--270},
  year={2015},
  publisher={publisher}
}

@article{author3,
  title={Article Title},
  author={Author and Author},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={7},
  number={6},
  pages={259--270},
  year={2015},
  publisher={publisher}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\title{Paper title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\cite{author1}
\cite{author2}
\cite{author3}

\raggedend
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]